# Scala.js: object literal with keys having colons in their names

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

A Javascript library I'm using expects objects like the following one:

```
{
  "paren:action": ...
}
```

As you can see, there is a colon in the name of the key/attribute, which is the reason I have to put the name in quotes.
At the moment, I'm trying to do create an identical object using Scala.js:

```
@JSExport
def create() = {
  literal(`paren:action` = ...)
}
```

I'm already using back ticks because without them, it doesn't even compile. However, the name of the resulting object is not as expected.

Example (executed in the Chrome console):

```
var a = { "paren:action": ... };
"paren:action" in a; // => true
Object.keys(a); // => ["paren:action"]

var b = ScalaJsApp().create();
"paren:action" in b; // => false
Object.keys(b); // => ["paren$colonaction"]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution to work around this problem is to use a `js.Dictionary`:

```
def create() = {
  js.Dictionary("paren:action" -> ...)
}
```

This of course should also work with `literal` but doesn't, due to nasty compiler internal details: `paren$colonaction` is how the Scala compiler internally represents the name `paren:action`, mainly due to restrictions on allowed characters in JVM bytecode.

Comment: `js.Dynamic.literal("paren:action" -> ...)` should work as well